# GET json API from twitch. getting Uncaught TypeError when im not online. JSON changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to get a value from JSON when I'm online streaming on twitch. The problem is when I'm not online, I get an error, `Uncaught TypeError`, because the JSON changes when I'm online/offline. How do I handle it when the return value changes?

```
$.ajax({
        headers: {
            'Client-ID' : 'xxx'
        },
        url: api_url + "?user_id=" + target,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = result.data[0].id;

        }
```

This works perfectly when I'm online. But when I'm offline the 
`result.data[0].id` does not exist and gives me:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined.

I hope I make myself understood, and I've searched ages for an answer online and here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Why not add a check before assigning it `if(result.data && result.data.length)`??

Comment: Before or after "success"? i tried to use if(result.data[0].id == 0) but that gave me an error

Comment: It should be within the success `if(result.data && result.data.length) document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = result.data[0].id`

Comment: Thank you Jaydip. Simple and effective. Worked perfectly. Thank you for helping beginners like me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd add a check before you try and do anything with the data, I'd also check for an error, it might not return one, but one possible solution might look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        'Client-ID' : 'xxx'
    },
    url: api_url + "?user_id=" + target,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result, err){
        if (!err && result && result.data && result.length) {
            document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = result.data[0].id;
        }
    });
```

Because the if statement will resolve from left to right, it will first check for the error, then if result is truthy (IE, not equal to undefined), then it's safe enough to assume you can check for result.data being truthy too and finally check for length being truthy, implying that you have at least one element, and are safe to access it.

You can find more info on 'truthy' here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: Feel free to ignore the _err_ part, it might not be how that API works

Comment: The if && works perfectly. Thank you for helping beginners like me!